# Syntax error in Terraform Azure VM resource creation

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I was new to Terraform, I am trying to use Terraform to provision virtual machines in Azure infrastructure. However, I'm encountering a syntax error that I can't seem to resolve. I have provided the code snippet below and the error message I'm receiving. Can someone please help me identify and fix the issue?

Terraform Code:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "my_vm" {
  name                  = "my-vm"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.my_nic.id]
    
  vm_size = "Standard_DS2_v2"

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option    = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }
    
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "myvm"
    admin_username = "myadmin"
    admin_password = "myp@ssw0rd"
  }
    
  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2022-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

Error Message:

> Error: Unsupported block type
> on main.tf line 43, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "my_vm":
> 43:   source_image_reference {
> Blocks of type "source_image_reference" are not expected here.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Is there something wrong with my syntax or configuration? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need the windows_virtual_machine configuration change the module to storage_image_reference or if you still wanna continue with the source_image_reference change the module to resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine and make changes in the configuration accordingly.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_virtual_machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a note in the `azurerm_virtual_machine` resource:

> The `azurerm_virtual_machine` resource has been superseded by the `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine` and `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine` resources. The existing `azurerm_virtual_machine` resource will continue to be available throughout the 3.x releases however is in a feature-frozen state to maintain compatibility - new functionality will instead be added to the `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine` and `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine` resources.

The [`azurerm_windows_virtual_machine` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_virtual_machine) has the [argument](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_virtual_machine#source_image_reference) you want.